# Roti Canai cooking tips?

Tags: asian-cuisine, flatbread

I am in love with Roti Canai, but I recently moved to a small island.

My local buddy at the farmers market sells Malaysian food, but she has been unable to make Roti Canai, so, what's the secret? Can anyone post a recipe or tips for getting it thin, nearly see-through, and crispy and soft when cooked?

Comment: if you don't know what this is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roti_canai

Comment: The link in the bottom of the Wikipedia page has a step-by-step guide with photographs.

Comment: Thanks, that second link is what I was looking for -- a method that does not require acrobatics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A step by step guide from the wikipedia page:

http://chefinyou.com/2009/11/roti-canai-recipe/

reproduced here in case wikipedia changes.